# Remove the domain name from User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-security

I have he following method inside my action method:-

```
repository.InsertOrUpdateRack(rj.Rack, User.Identity.Name, assetid);
```

But the user name generated from `User.Identity.Name`   will prefix the username with the domain name as follow:-

```
DOMAINNAME\username
```

So is there a way to force the `User.Identity.Name`  to retrieve the username only?
Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The domain forms part of the username so I don't think any of the methods/properties return what you need.  Can you not just do:

```
var userName = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
```

Not ideal but simple enough.  If you want to keep it nicely hidden away you could create an extension method on IIdentity.

The VB equivalent is (where UserWindowsName could be a variable or control used to display the Windows User Name):

```
Dim userName As WindowsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity
UserWindowsName = userName.Name.Split("\"c)(1)
```

Comment: might be safer to use: `var userName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\').Last();` in case there is no domain prefix

Answer (score 0):

var name = Regex.Replace(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, @"^.*\", "");